# how can i add keys in val array in it

Tags: javascript

```
function asign(id){
return document.getElementById(id) ;
} 

function values(id){
return document.getElementById(id).value ;
}

asign('btn').addEventListener('click',validate,false) ;
 function validate(){
var ids = ['name1','name2','pass'] ;
var val = []; 
for(var i = 0 ; i<ids.length;i++){
         val.push(values(ids[i])) ;
   }

}
```

i want in val array also include keys in array like val[text]='name1' value and val[password]= 'pass' value so how can i done this .because in next i create different groups like text , password to validate in different types

Comment: use dictionary instead of storing into array..

Comment: var val = {}; 
for(var i = 0 ; i<ids.length;i++){
         val.value = values(ids[i]);
   }

}

Comment: use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Answer (score 0):

```
function asign(id){
return document.getElementById(id) ;
} 

function values(id){
return document.getElementById(id).value ;
}

asign('btn').addEventListener('click',validate,false) ;
 function validate(){
var ids = ['name1','name2','pass'] ;
var val = {}; 
for(var i = 0 ; i<ids.length;i++){
     val.value = values(ids[i]);
}

}
```

you can add additional params to the dictionary create..

```
    val.password = password;
```